# Can someone explain me the unix command the following command

Tags: unix

I want to validate the file. As per validation, I need to check the length of each column, null or not null and primary constant of that file.

```
cat File_name| awk -F '|' '{print NF}' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: What has the question title to do with what you wrote in the body, whatever _check_ or _primary constant_ might mean?

Answer (score 0):

This command split lines of the file on tokens using pipe `|` as delimiter, print number of tokens on each row (`NF` variable), sort the output (`sort` command) and on the end get only uniq numbers (`uniq` command).
The script can be optimised getting rid of `cat` command and combine it in `awk` and use parameter of `sort` to get uniq records:

```
awk -F '|' '{print NF}' file_name | sort -u
```